# If $X$ follows an $\operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$, does $1/X$ follow an $\operatorname{Exp}(1/ \theta)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I heard a teacher say that if $$X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$$
then $$\frac{1}{X} \sim \operatorname{Exp}\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$$
I don't trust this teacher because he has given us wrong answers before.

I tried to obtain this myself:

If $y = g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|$$
$$f_Y(y) = \theta \cdot e^{-\theta/y} \cdot \frac{1}{y^2}$$
where $1/y \in (0, +\infty)$.

I don't see an $\operatorname{Exp}(1/\theta)$ here. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tip: Use ```\exp``` to produce $\exp$.

Comment: I'm not particularly good with mathematical statistics, but I think [this link](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf) might be helpful?

Comment: @myself: actually don't do that for the exponential distribution. In this case use ```\operatorname{Exp}```.

Comment: If $y=g(x)=1/x$, then $g^{-1}(y) = 1/y = x$, and then you have $F_x(x)=F_x(g^{-1}(y))=F_y(y)$ and differentiate to get $f_y(y)$, so everything you did looks right to me. There are many alternative parameterizations of the exponential distribution though, so it would be nice for you to add that to you answer, like $f_x(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ or $f_x(x)=e^{-x/\lambda}$. Could that be part of it?  He just means something about notation?

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you for the document and the tips, theorem 1.1 of that file is what I used to arrive to my conclusion

Comment: @Renard thank you, he meant $f_x(x) = \lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda x}$ . I think he said it without thinking too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right and your transformation is correct!

But without doing any calculation, what is true is that $X\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\theta)=\Gamma(1;\theta)$

And this means that $\frac{1}{X}\sim \text{Inv-Gamma}$

See "Related distributions" in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)

Comment: thank you! this is very useful

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y= \frac1X$

- $\mathbb P(X \ge x)= \exp(-\theta x)$ for $x >0$
- $\mathbb P(Y \le \frac1x)= \exp(-\theta x)$
- $\mathbb P(Y \le y)= \exp(-\theta / y)$ which is certainly not the CDF of an exponential distribution

The density for $Y$ is then $\frac{\theta}{y^2} \exp(-\theta / y)$ which, as tommik says, is called an [inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If $1/X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1/\theta)$ as claimed, then $\theta = 1$ would suggest $1/X$ is exponential with rate $1$ if $X$ is exponential with rate $1$.  This of course is absurd, since for example $$\Pr[X > 1] = e^{-1}$$ but $$\Pr[1/X > 1] = \Pr[X < 1] = 1 - e^{-1}.$$

Comment: you are right, thank you, this is a nice way to refute the claim

Answer (score 1):

Three things to note for finding CDF and PDF of functions of rvs:

1. If the function is decreasing, the inequality sign flips
2. It's often easier to find CDF first.
3. Be careful if support of the function changes, e.g. if $Y= \log X$, you can only consider $X>0$ even if $X$ is defined on $X \leq 0$.
   In your case, for $X>0$:
   $$
   F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(\frac{1}{X} \leq y) = P(X \geq \frac{1}{y}) = \int_{\frac{1}{y}}^{\infty} \lambda e^{- \lambda x} dx = e^{-\frac{\lambda}{y}}
   $$
   Now use the definition of PDF (derivative of CDF):
   $$
   f_{Y}(y) = \frac{\lambda}{y^2}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{y}}, y > 0 
   $$